# Python Bit: ConnectionError: Transaction broadcast failed, or Unspents were already used

Tags: python, bitcoin

So I'm trying to make a transaction using the [Bit](https://pypi.org/project/bit/) library. Everything was working on testnet, but once I tried my script on mainnet, it return this error everytime :

> ConnectionError: Transaction broadcast failed, or Unspents were
> already used.

I tried to wait (until some additional confirmations, checked that both wallets where in mainnet but I can't get it to work... Here is my code :

```
if sys.argv[1] == 'withdraw':
        if len(sys.argv) > 3:
            my_key = Key(sys.argv[2])
            my_key.get_balance()
            total_bytes = (148 * len(my_key.get_unspents())) + (34 * 2) + 10 + len(my_key.get_unspents())
            total_fees = total_bytes * network.get_fee(fast=True)
            tx_hash = my_key.send([(sys.argv[3], int(my_key.balance_as('satoshi')) - total_fees, 'satoshi')])
            print('{"status": "success","tx_hash":'+tx_hash+'}')
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just saw that the Bit documentation had an option to move all funds from a wallet to another :

> tx_hash = my_key.send([], leftover=sys.argv[3])

leave the outputs blank and put your address in leftover :)